# Proof on greatest lower bound and least upper bound.

Tags: real-analysis

If $A$ is a non-empty bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}$, and $B$ is the set of all upper bounds of $A$, prove that 
$$glb(B)= lub(A)$$

**My reasoning and thinking**:

The set of upper bounds may be infinite countable set, right? 
 Also all the upper bounds (elements of set $B$) are greater than or equal to $x$ for all $x$ in $A$, using definition of upper bound.
Then it is  $glb(B)$, I am not getting what does it mean? As $y$ is an element of $B$, then is $glb$ of $y$ is $y$ itself?

Any help/hint please.

Comment: Since $A$ has an upper bound $b$, any member of  $S= \{c : c\geq b \}$  is an upper bound for $ A ,$ and  $S$  is not countable.And it's irrelevant to your question

Comment: The set of upper bounds of A is infinite and in fact uncountable, and as @user254665 said, that has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Then, what fact will help me out? It was my duty to explain what I know about the terms related to question. I am still waiting for the proper reasoning and answer.

Comment: @user254665. Let me clear one more thing, whether or not we are able to write uncountable set in {  } ?

Comment: @ Gudson Chou. Well, the number l is said to be sup of A if it is upper bound of  A and no number less than l can be upper bound of A.

Comment: Re "whether or not we are able to write uncountable set in { }" I'm not sure what you're uncertain about (I don't quite understand what the question is). If you mean, can we indicate an uncountable set using "set builder" notation e.g. $\{x \in X \mid blahBlah(x, X)\}$, then Yes we can. Of course we can't *list* the elements of an infinite set between curly braces, we can at best use "...".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, observe that for any $b \in B$, $lub(A) \le b$, 
because $b \in B$ is an upper bound of $A$ and $lub(A)$ is the least of them. So $lub(A)$ is a lower bound of B, hence:
$$lub(A) \le glb(B) \text{.}
$$

Because $lub(A)$ is an upper bound of $A$, $lub(A) \in B$ by definition of $B$. Thus, 
$$glb(B) \le lub(A)\text{.}
$$
Hence $lub(A) = glb(B)$.

Comment: Logical and perfect answer.

Comment: This sort of comment is discouraged [this one, not yours], but: thank you :)

Comment: @ user5273591 I simplified it - no more proof by contradiction (hope you don't miss it ;/ )

Comment: Yes, definitely not. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

(1)For any  $S\subset R$,  if glb$(S) \in S$ then glb$(S)=\min (S)$.....(2) Let $z=$glb$(B)$. Suppose   $z$ is not an upper bound for $A $ . Then $z<x$ for some $x\in A$. But then (by the definition of $B$), no member of $B$ is less than $x $, so  $x$ is a lower bound for $B$. So $B$ has a lower bound (namely, $x$) that is greater  than the greatest lower bound of $B$ (namely, $z$),which is absurd..... (3.) Therefore  the supposition in (2) is false : So it must be true that $z$ is an upper bound for $A$,that is, glb$(B)=z\in B$. So, by (1), $z$ is the least member of $B $ That is, $z$ is the least of the upper bounds of $A$. $$\text { So we have   lub}(A)=z=\text {glb}(B).$$

Comment: Not so concise as BrianO....Conciseness is not my best talent.